# How change API params in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

It's almost 3AM and i just don't understand how change API params for **language_code**, i want to change it in **'en'** and **'ru'**, and maybe some others but even logic with to params doesn't work

I''m tried it with hooks and localStorage, but it's rerender all except API request

```
const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState('en')
   const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
    axios({

      // other logic (there is key :) )

      }, "params": {
        "language_code": `${language}`
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setResponseData(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [fetchData])

// here i'm fetch data
<button className='buttondata' type='button' onClick={fetchData}>Click for Data</button>
```

Maybe i'm just don't understand something with mounting or work with API

Comment: are you getting some new language in `response.data` ? .if yes then update your state `setLanguage(response.data.language_code)` //update with the key you receive from backend . add this below `setResponseData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm made some strange solution, maybe it will need someone in the future. Just save state in localStorage and call it with useState through radio buttons and spread operator:

```
 const saved = localStorage.getItem("language");
  const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved) || 'en';

  
  const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState(initialValue || 'en');

  
  

  localStorage.setItem("language", JSON.stringify(language));


  console.log(language)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setLanguage(event.target.value);
    window.location.reload(true);
  };

  const controlProps = (item) => ({
    checked: language === item,
    onChange: handleChange,
    value: item,
    name: 'color-radio-button-demo',
    inputProps: { 'aria-label': item },
    
  });
```

There is controlProps function with Radio buttons:

```
<Radio {...controlProps('en')} />
                <Radio {...controlProps('ru')} color="secondary" />
                <Radio {...controlProps('de')} color="success" />
                <Radio {...controlProps('fr')} color="default" />
                <Radio
                  {...controlProps('ru')}
                  sx={{
                    color: pink[800],
                    '&.Mui-checked': {
                      color: pink[600],
                    },
                  }}
                />
```